ASP.NET Core with React Typescript : Error: Could not create certificate
So basically, on the get-go when I try to run my project under Visual Studio using full stack React and ASP.NET Core, I get this error
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" --import file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/WebStorm%202024.2.4/plugins/nodeJS/js/ts-file-loader/node_modules/tsx/dist/loader.cjs "C:\Users\main\Documents\Programming\Project and Freelance\projects\VehicleRentalProject\vehiclerentalproject.client\vite.config.ts"


There was an error exporting the HTTPS developer certificate to a file.
file:///C:/Users/main/Documents/Programming/Project%20and%20Freelance/projects/VehicleRentalProject/vehiclerentalproject.client/vite.config.ts:1
import{fileURLToPath,URL}from"node:url";import{defineConfig}
from"vite";import plugin from"@vitejs/plugin-react";import fs  from"fs";import path from"path";import child_process from"child_process";import{env}from"process";const baseFolder=env.APPDATA!==void 0&&env.APPDATA!==""?${env.APPDATA}/ASP.NET/https:${env.HOME}/.aspnet/https;const certificateName="vehiclerentalproject.client";const certFilePath=path.join(baseFolder,${certificateName}.pem);const keyFilePath=path.join(baseFolder,${certificateName}.key);if(!fs.existsSync(certFilePath)||!fs.existsSync(keyFilePath)){if(0!==child_process.spawnSync("dotnet",["dev-certs","https","--export-path",certFilePath,"--format","Pem","--no-password"],{stdio:"inherit"}).status){throw new Error("Could not create certificate.")}}const target=env.AS
PNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT?https://localhost:${env.ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT}:env.ASPNETCORE_URLS?env.ASPNETCORE_URLS.split(";")[0]:"https://localhost:7017";var vite_con
fig_default=defineConfig({plugins:[plugin()],resolve:{alias:{"@":fileURLToPath(new URL("./src",import.meta.url))}},server:{proxy:{"^/weatherforecast":{target,secure:false}},port:5173,https:{key:fs.readFileSync(keyFilePath),cert:fs.readFileSync(certFilePath)}}});export{vite_config_default as default};
> Error: Could not create certificate.

I checked the path, and the certificate already exists. Also, it seems as though there is also a similar bug like this on the Angular ASP.NET Core side, and solves it by modifying the aspnetcore-https.js file
const baseFolder = //etc...

fs.mkdirSync(baseFolder, { recursive: true });

But I can't find the aspnetcore-https.js file or even its equivalent.

The issue has been discussed here.It' a .Net 8 build bug and Version >= 8.0.403 are affected ,you could try to install a former version and  switch the dotnet sdk version when you debug
For example,via gobal.json
dotnet new globaljson --sdk-version 8.0.402

